# Concatenation in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, api, if-statement, boolean

I am working on enom API Integration.

I am using code that give me output TRUE/FALSE (Boolean).. My following code is working good.

```
if ($result['YourDomain.co.uk'] == 1) { echo "Domain Avaliable";} else { echo "Domain Already Taken"; }
```

BUT I want to use Concatenate dynamic values in the array but its not WORKING Please HELP.. Code as following.

```
$sld = "YourDomain";
$tld = "co.uk";

$dname = $sld.$tld;

if ($result[$dname] == 1) { echo "Domain Avaliable";} else { echo "Domain Already Taken"; }
```

Comment: should be like this `$tld = ".co.uk";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
$dname = $sld.".".$tld;
```

you are missing `.`